# Print different pages of pdf in different trays of printer in java

Tags: java, printing, tray

I am currently in a process of printing different pages of a PDF to multiple trays in a single print job. Lets assume there are 10 pages. First 3 pages are to be printed using paper from Tray 1, next four using Tray 2 and the remaining from Tray 1.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: Check out http://blog.idrsolutions.com/2010/01/printing-pdf-files-from-java/ for printing PDF from Java

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and came sadly to the conclusion that this is simple not supported by the java API.

There are other printing libraries, that may support this like Cups4J for Linux systems. But this wasn't an option for me, so i ended up with splitting the printjob in two printjobs and print every job on a different mediatray.